# Missing mysql.sock file

Tags: mysql

I updated MySQL with yum.

And it doesn't start now.

I try `find / | grep mysql.sock`.

I can't see any sock file.

How can I create it? Or any possible solution?

Thanks.

Comment: mysql.sock file creates when server is started

Comment: i can't start the service

Comment: what kind of error you get when starting mysql server?

Comment: mysql.log says:

Comment: 120531 10:14:24 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
120531 10:14:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120531 10:14:24 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
120531 10:14:24 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-bdb'
120531 10:14:24 [ERROR] Aborting

120531 10:14:24 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120531 10:14:24 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

Comment: You have two problems: 1. You have a `skip-bdb` option in your config somewhere, which is no longer valid for current MySQL. 2. You have a `skip-innodb` option in your config as well which is disabling MySQL's only good storage engine.

Comment: @Kronokrator Adding the log to your question instead of a comment would make it much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like mysqld isn't running at all.   Be sure to remove the invalid/old options from /etc/my.cnf and then check in the log that mysqld starts correctly.